# get a clojure function's code

Tags: clojure

Is there a way in clojure to get a function's code after the function has been loaded?

Ie. without doing something like [untested]

```
(defmacro blat [x] `(do (def code ~(quote (mexpand-all x)))
                        ~x)))
(blat (defn func [abc] (...)))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can get the source of a symbol using the `clojure.repl/source` function. However, this only works if the var for which the symbol resolves to is in a .clj file on the classpath. You can't, for example, do this:

```
user=> (defn foo [x] x)
#'user/foo
user=> (require 'clojure.repl)
nil
user=> (clojure.repl/source foo)
Source not found
nil
```

Comment: hmm. (mexpand-all (read-string (source-fn 'foo))) is about what I want